# Cannnot find latest iOS version in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently have macOS 13.4.1 installed on a Macbook Air M1, along with Xcode 13.4.1 and command line tools 13.4.1 (`xcodebuild -version`). However I'm unable to see the latest iOS version (16.5.1) in Xcode Settings > Platform > Add.

[image]
[image]

I have tried restarting Xcode and Mac, clearing derived data etc. with no results. Any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Comment: There are no simulator images available with ios 16.5.1.  If 16.4 isn't sufficient for some reason and you really need to test on this version then you will need to use a physical device.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah. I got a rejection in review saying that the app doesn't open on 16.5.1. If thats the case please post as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The chances of 16.5.1 being the problem are low. They will just tell you the version they tested on for your information. You should always check your submissions with a TestFlight build on a real device as that is what Apple will review

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm unable to see the latest iOS version in Xcode Settings > Platform > Add.

If you're hoping to see the iOS 17 beta (arguably the "latest" iOS version), you'll probably need to first install the Xcode 15.0 beta. Major iOS updates often rely on major Xcode updates.

Comment: The latest version is 16.5.1. As you can see from the screenshots it appears to be missing. I'm not talking about installing beta.